# How to configure settings.DATABASES?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

./manage.py syncdb shows some error

> (ENV)vijay@vijay-Ideapad-Z570:~/nightybuild/heroku-landing$ ./manage.py syncdb
>   ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
>  value. Check settings documentation for more details.
>   (ENV)vijay@vijay-Ideapad-Z570:~/nightybuild/heroku-landing$

in my settings.py

> DATABASES = {
>                       'default': {
>                                  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
>                                  'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
>                                  # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
>                                  'USER': '',
>                                 'PASSWORD': '',
>                                'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
>                                'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
>       }

but my app running successfully in heroku. when deploy its automatically heroku postgres confiqured. But in the local development its showing this error .

Can you please tell guide me how to set database for local?

Answer (score 0):

What type of database are you using? Postgres, MySQL, SQLite? That will be your `ENGINE` value.

Also, what is your local postgres username and password? And your database name?

Below is an example with a **postgres** database named **testdb** with the username **myusername** and password **mypassword**:

```
DATABASES = {
                 'default': {
                       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
                       'NAME': 'testdb',
                       'USER': 'myusername',
                      'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
                     'HOST': '',
                     'PORT': '',
}
```

You may need to alter depending on your needs. The biggest change will likely be your `ENGINE` value. Change `postgresql_psycopg2` to `mysql` if using MySQL or `sqlite` if using SQLite. Also, if using SQLite, you won't have values for `USER` and `PASSWORD`.

Comment: What should i do for this error ? @Alex ImportError: No module named psycopg2.extensions

Comment: You'll need to install the packages first. Try `pip install psycopg2`.

Comment: set `HOST: 'localhost',` without this sometime strange errors will occur